# Declare var in jquery.live() which can be used in all functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

Is it possible to declare a `var` in `jquery.live()` (as well as `.delegate()` & `.on()`) which can be used in all functions?

Example:

```
$("#s4-leftpanel-content ul.root > li.static > a").live({
    click: function (event) {
        var hasChildren = $(this).parent('li').children('ul').length > 0;
        if (hasChildren) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#s4-leftpanel-content ul.root li.static > ul.static").hide();
            $(this).parent('li').children('ul').toggle();
        }
    },
    mouseover: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
    }
});
```

Lets say I want to use the bool var `hasChildren` in the `mouseover` and `mouseout` function as well, do I then have to declare that `var` again in these 2 functions or is there a way in which I can just declare it globally within this current object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables declared with `var` are always local to the context, in this case the event handler.

You have three possibilities:

**Create the variable in a scope reachable by all event handlers**

For example:

```
(function() {
    var hasChildren;

    $("#s4-leftpanel-content ul.root > li.static > a").live({
        // ...
        mouseover: function () {
           hasChildren = $(this).parent('li').children('ul').length > 0;
           $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        },
        //...
    });
}());
```

The self-invoking function creates a new scope. `hasChildren` is only accessible by the event handlers and does not leak into global scope.

**Use [`.data()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

`.data()` allows you to attach arbitrary data to a DOM element.

```
//...
click: function (event) {    
    var hasChildren = $(this).data('hasChildren');
    if (hasChildren) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#s4-leftpanel-content ul.root li.static > ul.static").hide();
        $(this).parent('li').children('ul').toggle();
    }
},
mouseover: function () {
    $(this).data('hasChildren', $(this).parent('li').children('ul').length > 0);
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
},
//...
```

*Update:*

As @pimvdb noted, as `mouseover` is always triggered before `click`, you can just assign the value in your `mouseover` event handler and then access it in the other handlers either by `$(this).data('hasChildren')` or just `hasChildren`, depending on which way you choose (changed the code to reflect this).

**Factor out the computation**

As the determination whether the element has children or not only depends on the element itself, you could also factor out this line of code into an extra function and call it in every event handler:

```
(function() {
    function hasChildren(element) {
        return $(element).parent('li').children('ul').length > 0;
    }

    $("#s4-leftpanel-content ul.root > li.static > a").live({
        click: function (event) {    
            var hc = hasChildren(this);
            // ..
        },
        mouseover: function () {
           var hc = hasChildren(this);
           $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        },
        //...
    });
}());
```

Of course this comes with the cost of repeating the same computation, but you are at least not repeating code.

Comment: Although this is technically correct, I don't think this makes much sense since `mouseover` is fired *before* `click`. As I understand it, the OP wants to execute the `hasChildren` piece of code in all handlers without copying it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable at top like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hasChildren;
//then your js, jQuery codes
</script>
```